# What is the difference between "Image" and "picture"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference

I mean, What kinds of meaning does "image" express, but not "picture"?

Furthermore, what kinds of meaning can "picture" express but not "image"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its informative answer is available on sister site: [english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23716)

Comment: @hjpotter92 The fact that a question is on-topic on another site doesn't automatically make it off-topic here.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles – this site has a different audience, which might call for a more customized answer directed toward our audience. That said, I think more context needs to be added. "Everyday life" could include a computer file, a mural on a wall, some art in a museum, a thought in our heads, or a picture in a magazine. I think the O.P. needs to elaborate some more on what is being asked about, before we take this in a dozen different directions.

Comment: Update: Question now reopened after edit.

Comment: There are also meanings that both words can express but where one is preferred.  For example, people say both *picture file* and *image file*, but the latter is still preferred, especially in technical contexts.

Comment: What does a dictionary say about "Image"? What does it say about "Picture"?

Comment: @snailcar I think there are both picture files and image files in technical contexts. For example .iso files are usually image files and .jpg files are usually picture files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Image but not picture:**

> 1. *Reflection in the mirror.*
> 2. *Impression in others' eyes.* You need to improve your image.

**Picture but not Image:**

> 1. *Drawing.* I am drawing a picture.
> 2. *Photograph.* You are looking very pretty in this picture.
> 3. *Movie.* Please don't disturb, I am watching a picture.
> 4. *Situation.* A war is on. The picture is very gloomy on the border.

Comment: Well done! Although, as we enter into the age of digital photography, I wouldn't be surprised if _image_ slowly become more acceptable when dealing with photographs. Only time will tell.

Comment: I think you have a point. While using facebook or filling any online form, it asks- 'upload your image.'

Comment: About "Picture" , I never heard/read the examples of 1&3 . Are you sure those are valid?

Comment: Oh yes, very much.

Comment: Idiomatically, "Going to the pictures" is a phrase referring to going to the cinema, "Moving Pictures" or "Motion Picture" are older terms for movies ("movie" being a fore-shortened colloquial term for Moving Picture).

Comment: What about a diagram (e.g. NYSE-chart) that is saved on the computer as a jpeg? Can I say "picture"? Or can it only be an "image"?