# Photo Vs. Picture Vs. Image : What is the difference between them?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

Sometimes I hear people say 'Photos' and some time I hear them say 'Pictures'. In addition, I sometimes encounter the word 'Image'. In my understanding I feel that all of them are the same but I'm not sure about this. So what is the difference between them?

When should I use 'Photo'?

When should I use 'Picture'?

When should I use 'Image'?

Comment: This is 2/3rds of a duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9690/what-is-the-difference-between-image-and-picture

Comment: @J.R. I should pick on you about it being either "2/3" or "two thirds", but not both.  :)

Comment: @Hellion - You got me; although "2/3rds" seems to be acceptable in headlines (see [A](http://9to5mac.com/2011/09/21/google-23rds-of-our-mobile-search-comes-from-apples-ios/) [B](http://theolympiareport.com/yakima-voters-will-consider-their-own-23rds-majority-standard/) [C](http://crosscut.com/2013/02/28/olympia-2013/113217) [D](http://www.freep.com/article/99999999/NEWS15/120928068) [E](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-503544_162-57369226-503544) [F](http://www.paymentsnews.com/2006/11/survey_finds_23.html)) – so maybe it's acceptable in an SE comment, too? :^)

Comment: @J.R. Not my fault if a bunch of headline editors are uneducated....

Comment: @Hellion - Okay, you win... [*hangs head in shame*]. (I could just edit or delete my comment, but then your brilliant catch would be rendered moot.)

Comment: @J.R. You mean you don't pronounce it "two-thirds-rds"? I thought everyone did! ;)

Comment: Et tu, @WendiKidd ?

Comment: This is actually a more comprehensive question than the one cited by @J.R. and it is more like 3/2ves of a duplicate.

Answer (score 39):

A photo, short for photograph, is always taken with a camera.

A picture is the most general term for any representation of a person, an object or a landscape. It can be a painting or a pencil drawing, etc.

The delimitation of image and picture has its difficulties. "image" has an overlapping area with "picture" and it has uses of its own where "image" is preferred. For example.

- God created Man in his own image. - Here the idea of likeness is expressed.
- Firms are concerned about the image the public has of them. And they try to create a positive image by public relations.

The word "image" has a many-sided character and it is useful to have a look at a dictionary about special uses of image.

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/image

Comment: This is excellent. I would just add that from a computer science / software stand point (mine), `image` should be used when talking about any type of image file. A picture or a photo does not encompass computer generated images, engineering drawings, etc. So if you handle images uniquely, such as by showing thumbnails, use `isAnImage` instead of `isAPhoto` or `isAPicture`.

Answer (score 13):

And for the rest of the answer, a **photograph** is specifically an image or picture formed by the capture of the light from the subject on a light-sensitive medium, originally glass plates, then film, now usually an electronic sensor. A **picture** can include drawings, paintings, or computer-generated images.